# Couchbase - Auto generate key with user defined suffix

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-webflux

I want to save an employee object in couchbase using spring boot java. I am using reactive couchbase driver. My requirement is to save the employee object with employeeId suffixed with hard coded string "-EMPLOYEETYPE".

Example: 
Object to couchbase from Java Application:

```
{ "employeeId" : "12345", "lname" :"ltest", "fname" : "ftest"}
```

While saving to couch base, key supposed to be generated like

```
"12345-EMPLOYEETYPE"
```

**Below code is not working, kindly guide me how to achieve it.**
Note: I am using lombok so there are no getters and setters.

```
@Document
public final class Employee {

        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationStrategy.USE_ATTRIBUTES,delimiter="-EMPLOYEETYPE")
        private String id;

        @IdAttribute
        private String employeeId;
}
```

Comment: "Will the below code work fine ?" - onSO, the poster who asks a question is supposed to say whether their code works and/or what isn't working about it. Have you tried your code?

Comment: Could you tell me if  , the id is a autoincrement number ? or a couchDB sequence ?

Comment: @user_D_A__, Here I am not trying to generate id out of auto increment or sequence. I want to create the key based on employeeId with some suffix. Here employeeId from input itself will be unique. Reason why i need to append suffix is, couchbase puts all type of (employee, address, etc) document into single bucket. There may be a case where employeeId and addressId would conflict. To avoid it, I want to add a suffix relevant to the type of object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution. We need to create an instance variable with suffix string literal assigned to it, and annotate with @IdSuffix. (For prefix, @IdPrefix). This field will not be persisted into couchbase and only used to generate id for document.

```
@Document
public final class Employee {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationStrategy.USE_ATTRIBUTES,delimiter="-")
    private String id;

    @IdAttribute
    private String employeeId;

    @IdSuffix
    private String suffix = "EMPLOYEETYPE";
}
```

Reference Doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.autokeygeneration.configuration